# What is the geometric meaning of correlation matrix

Tags: correlation, interpretation, covariance, geometry, projection

I recently read this article explaining the geometric meaning of covariance matrix.

http://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/geometric-interpretation-covariance-matrix/

My question is : is there an intuitive, geometric meaning for **correlation** matrix as well?

If I have $m$ samples (all centered at $0$ for each dimension), each of $n$ dimension, I stack them as a matrix $X$ , which has $m$ rows, $n$ columns, then I standardize each columns of $X$ to get $\bar{X}$

$$\bar{X}^{T}\bar{X}$$

This should be the correlation matrix, right?

Now I have a new sample coming in, $x$, which is a vector of $n$

what is the geometric meaning of $$\bar{X}^T \bar{X}x \text{ ?}$$

Can anyone explain?

Comment: You should speak of "$m$ samples", but rather of a sample of size $m,$ or a sample consisting of $m$ observations.